# Jquery upload request sent same as the number of files I selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am currently working on creating an image uploading page using jQuery and PHP. However, I have encountered some issues in my code. When I select multiple files to upload, the code uploads the same number of files multiple times. For example, if I select 2 files, it uploads those 2 files twice, and if I select 3 files, it uploads those 3 files thrice.

I have also implemented a PHP script to handle multiple file uploads simultaneously, but even after doing so, the issue persists. Additionally, when I remove the multiple file upload feature, the code only uploads the last file from the selected multiple files.

```
var files;
var currentFileIndex;
var isUploading = false; // Flag to check if a file is currently being uploaded

$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (e) {
  files = e.target.files;
  currentFileIndex = 0;
  uploadNextFile();
  $('.uploadProgress').addClass('show');
});
    
function uploadNextFile() {
  var progressBar = $('.js-upload-progress-bar');
  var uploadForm = $('#uploadForm');
  
  if (currentFileIndex < files.length) {
    if (!isUploading) { // Check if a file is currently being uploaded
      isUploading = true; // Set flag to true when starting to upload a file
      var file = files[currentFileIndex];
      var fileSize = file.size / (1024 * 1024); // File size in MB
      var fileType = file.type;
      var isImage = fileType.startsWith('image/');
      var isVideo = fileType.startsWith('video/');

      if (fileSize <= 1024 && (isImage || isVideo)) { // Validate file size and type
        var previewSrc = isVideo ? '../assets/images/icons/icons-video.png' : URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $('.js-previewImg').attr('src', previewSrc);
        $('.js-uploadStatus').text('Uploading ' + (currentFileIndex + 1) + '/' + files.length); // Update upload status

        var formData = new FormData(uploadForm[0]);
        formData.set('file', file); // Set current file in FormData

        $.ajax({
          url: 'upload.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
              if (e.lengthComputable) {
                var progress = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                progressBar.val(progress);
              }
            });
            return xhr;
          },
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            currentFileIndex++;
            isUploading = false; // Reset flag when current file upload is completed
            uploadNextFile(); // Upload next file after completing the current one
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
            currentFileIndex++;
            isUploading = false; // Reset flag when current file upload is completed
            uploadNextFile();
          }
        });
      } else {
        // File validation failed, show error
        console.log('File validation failed');
        currentFileIndex++;
        isUploading = false; // Reset flag when current file upload is completed
        uploadNextFile();
      }
    }
  } else {
    $('.js-uploadStatus').text('Upload Successful');
    setTimeout(function() {  
      $('.uploadProgress').removeClass('show'); 
      $('input[type="file"]').val(''); // Reset file input value
      isUploading = false; // Reset flag when uploading is completed
    }, 1000);
    progressBar.val(0); // Reset progress bar
    currentFileIndex = 0; // Reset current file index
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, your code sends each file once - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5w2jp4dr/1/ (to show it, open the browser's network tab. Then click on Choose files in the form, and choose 2 or 3 files, or however many you want. It will then generate one AJAX request in the network tab for each one. The payloads show one file in each.)

Comment: `var formData = new FormData(uploadForm[0]);` - the `FormData` constructor, when called with a form element as parameter, will _already_ encode the complete form with all currently selected data, for submission. You are then adding _more_ data to this, `formData.set('file', file);` - so you are appending your file, which was already included in the data set, a second time here.

Comment: @CBroe How do I upload images 1 by 1, so that I can show the progress report of each file and the preview of each file which is uploading now, (1 image and 1 progress) at a time.

Comment: Create an _empty_ FormData object, and then append your file to that.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, but as that JSFiddle I made shows, since the OP has named their manually-added formdata object `file`, it looks like it overwrites the one from the form, so actually it seems to have the intended effect. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ADyson we have not even seen OP's form yet, so the field could be named something else.